# How do I encourage emacs to follow the compilation buffer

Tags: emacs

Occasionally when I'm compiling, I have to scroll up my *compilation* buffer to see the details of an error. At this point, emacs stops "following" my compilation buffer, i.e., scrolling to automatically display new output.

I'm using Aqumacs on OS X. Any idea how I can "reattach" or re encourage the compilation buffer to follow again?

Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure about aquamacs but for me (Emacs 23/Debian) I just go in the compilation window and place my cursor at the end of the window which will attach and follow (you can go to another window and it will still follow).

Comment: Can this be made automatically? I hate it when todays fast computers fills up my compilation buffer so quickly that I can't set the cursor at the end ;-)

Comment: @Thomas, You can get to the end with one command: `M->`.  That'll work no matter how fast output is scrolling.  But see @thohr's answer for how to make it scroll automatically.

Comment: Doesn't work on LaTeX compile window. But @tsohr answer bellow works perfectly.

Answer (score 90):

Put in your ~/.emacs file

```
  ;; Compilation output
  (setq compilation-scroll-output t)
```

or even

```
  (setq compilation-scroll-output 'first-error)
```

to make it scroll to the first error.

Comment: That worked perfectly for me -- wondering what the syntax of an 'error' is, so I can make debug output to mimic that.  Time to go digging.  But this answer will save me so much aggravation!

Comment: I always like to work with the customize-framework, but your mileage may vary. In this case: M-x customize-variable compilation-scroll-output.

Answer (score 5):

Try using <kbd>M-x auto-revert-tail-mode</kbd> or <kbd>M-x auto-revert-mode</kbd>. Taken from [official documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Reverting.html):

> One use of Auto-Revert mode is to
>   “tail” a file such as a system log, so
>   that changes made to that file by
>   other programs are continuously
>   displayed. To do this, just move the
>   point to the end of the buffer, and it
>   will stay there as the file contents
>   change. However, if you are sure that
>   the file will only change by growing
>   at the end, use Auto-Revert Tail mode
>   instead (auto-revert-tail-mode). It is
>   more efficient for this. Auto-Revert
>   Tail mode works also for remote files.

So, as Chmouel already noted, just moving point to end of buffer will also work.

Comment: Moving the cursor to the end of the file seems to work. auto-revert-tail-mode complains that "this buffer is not a file"; so perhaps it only works for files, not for compilation output?